# Slack Thumbnail url from Slack api for any file type like Image, Pdf, Audio, Video etc

Tags: thumbnails, slack-api

I need to extract thumbnail url for any particular file.

while accessing the **https://slack.com/api/files.list**
I saw that for image thumbnail key as[image]files : thumb_64, thumb_80, 360 type JSON keys

For pdf it is like[image]

& similarly for other file type it has different different json key to find thumbnail.

**So for every particular file type should i find thumbnail key manually. Any shortcut to find thumbnail key for all file type.**

I need to pass my thumbnail url to some service no matter what kind of file it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [file object type](https://api.slack.com/types/file#file-objects__thumbnails) gives some information on this. But as you have already noticed, it doesn't mention PDF or other file types.

> If a thumbnail is available for the file, the URL to a 64x64 pixel
> will be returned as the thumb_64 prop.
>
> The thumb_80 prop (when present) contains the URL of an 80x80 thumb.
> Unlike the 64px thumb, this size is guaranteed to be 80x80, even when
> the source image was smaller (it's padded with transparent pixels).
>
> A variable sized thumb will be returned as thumb_360, with its longest
> size no bigger than 360 (although it might be smaller depending on the
> source size). Dimensions for this thumb are returned in thumb_360_w
> and thumb_360_h.
>
> In the case where the original image was an animated gif with
> dimensions greater than 360 pixels, we also created an animated
> thumbnail and pass it as thumb_360_gif.
>
> Depending on the original file's size, you may even find a thumb_480,
> thumb_720, thumb_960, or thumb_1024 property.

I did try looking through the Slack client's JS code (search for `thumb_pdf` in `client-boot-imports.XXXX.min.js`), and found a code block where it seems to be defining possible `thumb_*` keys. While it is not conclusive, you may look for these fields in the API response and fallback to a default image for each supported format.

[image: screenshot of Slack client side JS code]

Comment: Thanks Jai your analysis is quite close to my question, I also had a look on this thumb_* they are making depends on file type passed, for text file etc they are not even making any thukmb_txt same for other file type.

Comment: If you notice, Slack itself doesn't display a thumbnail for all files in its file browser. Just like how the official Slack client behaves, you could fallback to default icons for each type of file, if no `thumb_*` field is available in the API response.